# sort aggregated field in crosstab query sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a crosstab query and I need to sort an aggregated field in descending order. Is there a way to do this? Price is the field I need sorted.

```
TRANSFORM Sum([dbo_RX Reporting].Price) AS SumOfPrice
SELECT [dbo_RX Reporting].[Master Drug Name], Sum([dbo_RX Reporting].Price) AS Total
FROM [dbo_RX Reporting]
WHERE ((([dbo_RX Reporting].[Therapeutic Class]) Like "*Analg*") AND (([dbo_RX Reporting].Period) Like "2018*") AND (([dbo_RX Reporting].[Plan Name])="Alabama"))
GROUP BY  [dbo_RX Reporting].[Master Drug Name]
PIVOT [dbo_RX Reporting].Period;


Master Drug Name           Total    201804       201805       201806    201807
ACETAMINOPHEN           $1,311.72   $335.27     $330.92     $286.47     $359.06 
ACETAMINOPHEN/CODEINE   $2,399.87   $891.89     $543.60     $658.08     $306.30 
ALLOPURINOL               $976.27   $215.98     $234.16     $263.96     $262.17 
Amrix                   $1,065.14             $1,065.14         
APAP                    $1,526.08   $415.34     $524.56     $297.04     $289.14
```

Comment: `ORDER BY Total DESC`. It is a bit unclear what you want to achieve. Sample data and desired resultset would be helpful

Comment: I need to sort in descending order by the 'Total' column. I tried your suggestion and got the error 'The MS Access' database engine does not recognize 'Total' as a valid field name or expression.

Comment: `ORDER BY SumOfPrice`

Comment: Same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

Because the crosstab query is special type of MS Access query, it will not run a usual `ORDER BY` clause. While in an aggregate query you can reference the calculated, aggregate column in `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT [dbo_RX Reporting].[Master Drug Name], Sum([dbo_RX Reporting].Price) AS [Total]
FROM [dbo_RX Reporting]
WHERE ((([dbo_RX Reporting].[Therapeutic Class]) Like 'Analg*') 
   AND (([dbo_RX Reporting].Period) Like '2018*') 
   AND (([dbo_RX Reporting].[Plan Name])='Alabama'))
GROUP BY  [dbo_RX Reporting].[Master Drug Name]
ORDER BY Sum([dbo_RX Reporting].Price) DESC
```

For a crosstab query, you need to save the original query and run a second query to call `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT * FROM myCrosstabQ q ORDER BY q.[Total] DESC
```

---

And no you cannot run a `TRANSFORM` in a subquery as a derived table to process only one query.

```
SELECT * FROM (TRANSFORM ...) q ORDER BY q.[Total] DESC
```

However, the converse with a `TRANSFORM` based off a subquery derived table is valid in MS Access SQL:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(dt.Price) AS SumOfPrice
SELECT dt.[Master Drug Name], Sum(dt.Price) AS [Total]
FROM (SELECT TOP 5 * FROM [dbo_RX Reporting]) dt
WHERE (((dt.[Therapeutic Class]) Like '*Analg*') 
   AND ((dt.Period) Like '2018*') AND ((dt.[Plan Name])='Alabama'))
GROUP BY dt.[Master Drug Name]
PIVOT dt.Period;
```